# How can users see the people that are in dynamic distribution lists?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010, distribution-lists

My boss is pissed that I created dynamic distribution groups and now he can't expand the list of people that're in those groups.

I want the dynamic-ness of it because I want it to be easy to manage but I want him to be able to see who's in the list.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the membership isn't calculated until the message hits Exchange.  You'll need to decide between expandability and dynamic lists.